# i am very confused how parameters and return

Tags: java, class, parameters, int, return

After I execute this code, the output is  the output is 
3 0
1 2 4
could you please explain the output? does the parameter in the mystery class sequence play a role in this?

```
public class MysteryReturn {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int x = 1;
        int y=2;
        int z = 3;


           z = mystery(x,z,y);
           System.out.println(x + " "+y+" "+z);

    }
    public static int mystery(int z, int x, int y){
        z--;
        x =2*y +z;
        y=x-1;
        System.out.println(y + " "+ z);
        return x;
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no way your main method will print "1 2 4". Is there some code you've left out?

Comment: actually yes. sorry! there should be z = mystery(x,z,y); before print. I have corrected it above. the output is 
3 0
1 2 4
could you please explain the output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It prints 1 2 3, and you aren't calling `mystery` function, so it can't affect.

UPD. 
Question was updated, so lets look to your function

```
public static int mystery(int z, int x, int y) {
    z--;
    x = 2 * y + z;
    y = x - 1;
    System.out.println(y + " " + z);
    return x;
}
```

it can be rewtiren to

```
public static int mystery(int z, int x, int y) {
    return 2 * y + z-1;
}
```

and you calling it with arguments 1,3,2 - `mystery(1,3,2)` so answer becomes `2*2+1-1` which equals 4, so you have z=4, so

```
    System.out.println(x + " "+y+" "+z);
```

will print `1 2 4`